# Java Script to disable pop up blocker

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript... my customer wants the popup blocker needs to be disabled to use that XYZ application. I came to know that we cant write script to disable pop up for particular URL. Can someone guide me where i have option only Yes button, on clicking on Yes button i should be able to disable the popup blocker if not, user should not be able to proceed further.

1. system should check if pop up is enabled if yes, User should have
   option like Do you want to disable pop up and button should be only
   yes.
2. If they click on yes, user should be able to proceed further.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That is browser specific and a part of the user protection, you cannot change that.

Comment: show me the code have  you tried?

Comment: Daniel is right, there's no way you can disable the behavior with JavaScript (and in fact, you shouldn't have to).

Comment: I know this isn't an answer to your question (so I'm not writing it as one) but you should be aware that, apart from the technical limitations, there's the usability / ux nightmare to be taken into account: if you decide to use a popup blocker, do you really want to go to web sites that constantly bug you to deactivate it? I know this is the customer's request, but you have an opportunity (if not an obligation) here to inform the customer of possible alternatives to something that is not only impossible but also annoying. My two cents anyway.

Comment: It would be a security issue if it's possible.

Comment: The below script works in mozilla but not in IE.. request anyone to help me.<script type="text/JavaScript" language="JavaScript">
  var mine = window.open('','','width=1,height=1,left=0,top=0,scrollbars=no');
  if(mine)
     var popUpsBlocked = false
  else
 
{
     var popUpsBlocked = true
 
//  Display Error Message
 
 
 
}
 

 mine.close()
 </script>

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with JavaScript as this is, for the most part, a built-in browser property. If you want the user to disable their popup blocker on your application you should display a friendly notice asking them to do so.

> Sorry for the inconvenience, but in order to use our application you must enable popups.

Furthermore, most browsers will notify the user when a popup has been blocked, and ultimately it's the users' discretion which will determine whether they want to allow popups or not.

Comment: +1. BTW: If an application needs something like that, in 99% it should be redesigned...

Comment: Thanks for letting me know guys:) appreciate your quick response